# Best way to go about Deserialization in android?

Tags: android, xml-deserialization

I want to deserialize xml into an object on the android platform.Can you tell me which is the best way to go about it.If possible provide some links to the method you are referring to so  that i can get started with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deserialize XML you can use SIMPLE api. It is very easy to use. Download the file and use it in your program

Have a look here

http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#deserialize

Thanks
Deepak